# Django: Multiple databases one without model

Tags: django

I have two databases.
default has several models and works fine by itself.
When I add another database, it tries to creates tables from default database in the new database also. the new database does not have any models. All I am using it is to make a direct SQL query.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 
        ..
        ..
    },
    'payments': {
        'ENGINE': 
        ..
        ..
    },
}
```

Comment: Welcome! I don't know about Django, but this doesn't look like a very clear question yet. Could you please edit your question do describe what you want to happen and more about what you're seeing? That will make it easier for others to give you useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Django does allow for multiple databases.  You have to explicitly route to them for specific models and such though.  In your case, it sounds like you will want to route all of your django models to the default DB and define specific cases for when to query the payments DB.  I have linked a page, and specifically one section of that page for you to reference.  I could copy and paste pieces of that page, but I think you'll find it more useful to just follow that page's explanation.

You should find this page helpful: [MultiDB](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/)

This is particular will answer your question on managing two databases together: [managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases)